# Understanding useEffect's Ability to Update State

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to useEffect and trying to get my head around it. I have data coming in via useEffect when a user logs in. The below function for useEffect is called and **this does work but I have to refresh the page to see the value of "topic" change.** I understand that this is because the value hasn't changed since the page loaded.

**What I don't understand is:** how do I make that state refresh so when the page is first loaded the data from useEffect is shown instead of an empty string?

Thanks!

```
<p> Topic: {topic} </p>;

const [topic, setTopic] = useState("");

useEffect(async () => {
  const result = await axios({
    method: "GET",
    withCredentials: true,
    url: "http://localhost:4000/userData",
  }).then((res) => {
    setData(res.data);
    setTopic(res.data.topic);
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: NO need to use await and then together. Please have a look at how await syntax works.

Comment: I'm confused by the question. `topic` is getting set by useEffect, so you should just be able to use `{topic}` in your render. Perhaps the axios call isn't returning correctly, and `then` isn't being invoked?

Comment: @TusharShahi Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass async function inside the useEffect as a argument. But you can use async function inside the normal function of useEffect (write there and call there).

Here, empty [] means it runs only once when component mounted(loaded) and you write something [counter] then it runs everytime counter value changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
const fetchResults = async () => {
  const result = await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:4000/userData',
  });
  setData(result.data);
  setTopic(result.data.topic);
};
fetchResults();
}, []);
```

Comment: Actually this does work when I add the withCredentials: true, back in. However I still have to refresh the page to see it update the value of topic

Comment: Made this work by using props.SetTopic so the parent data changes and forces an update to the child

Answer (score 0):

You need to return what you want to be rendered from your function, just having `<p> Topic: {topic} </p>;` sitting there doesn't do anything. You need to move it to the bottom and wrap it in return, like:

```
return(
  <p> Topic: {topic} </p>
)
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan! I have it setup that way without luck